# elisp search functions

Tags: org-mode, org-export, search, functions

I'm trying to debug a piece of elisp that is in an orgmode template I'd like to use. (link [here](https://github.com/tsdye/org-bib-template/blob/master/annotated-biblio-template.org))
The problem is occurring in the source block that is supposed define the cite links.

```
(org-add-link-type 
 "cite" 'ebib
 (lambda (path desc format)
   (cond
    ((eq format 'html)
     (format "(<cite>%s</cite>)" path))
    ((eq format 'latex)
     (if (or (not desc) (equal 0 (search "cite:" desc)))
         (format "\\cite{%s}" path)
       (format "\\cite[%s][%s]{%s}"
               (cadr (split-string desc ";"))
               (car (split-string desc ";"))  path))))))
```

now when this block is run, it completes no problem and gives back a "Created cite link." message which is expected. However when you go to run the latex exporter, it gives me the following error.

```
Symbol's function definition is void: search
```

I have narrowed this down to the search command in the add link block, however I cannot figure out what it is supposed to be calling. From my research Common Lisp has a search function, but elisp does not. I've tried modifying the code to use every search like function build into emacs, and a few that are not such as the ebib-search with no success.
Do any of you have an idea as to what this is referencing?

Comment: It probably *is* the Common Lisp `search`. Add `(require 'cl)`, or else rename it to `cl-search` (which is autoloaded).

Comment: @phils you are absolutely right, do you want to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my research Common Lisp has a search function, but elisp does not.

elisp does in fact provide the Common Lisp `search` function in the `cl` library.

So adding `(require 'cl)` will fix the problem for the code as written.

Alternatively you could change `search` to `cl-search` which is an autoloaded alias.

Answer (score 4):

I think just using the built-in `string-match` instead of `search` is the most simple thing in this special case.

The modified code would look like:

```el
(org-add-link-type 
 "cite" 'ebib
 (lambda (path desc format)
   (cond
    ((eq format 'html)
     (format "(<cite>%s</cite>)" path))
    ((eq format 'latex)
     (if (or (not desc) (equal 0 (string-match "cite:" desc)))
         (format "\\cite{%s}" path)
       (format "\\cite[%s][%s]{%s}"
               (cadr (split-string desc ";"))
               (car (split-string desc ";"))  path))))))
```

Two remarks are in place:

1. The common lisp function `search` searches for literal strings while `string-match` searches for regular expressions. That does not matter here since there are no special characters in the search string `cite:`.
2. `string-match` modifies the match data. That does not matter here since the match data is modified anyway by `split-string`.

Comment: Interesting take, and I'll need to experiment with it a bit. But it looks like the problem was that I was missing the cl package, and I just needed to require it.  Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: @Nalisarc I know that `(require 'cl)` works. But, why pulling a heavy-weight package in when there is a light-weight built-in solution.

Comment: Oh I see, the two aren't quite identical, but upon closer inspection `string-match` _should_ do the same thing as `cl-search`.